# How to revoke copy access to a user postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I want to have a role based access for my Database. I've created a new user and want this user to only select access on Table but this also comes copy by default. I want to revoke this copy access to this user. Any help in this context would be really appreciable.

Thanks a Lot!!!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*copy access*"?

Comment: By "copy_access" I mean user should not be able to create replica of that table.

Comment: do you mean copy commond ? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: If the user can SELECT from the table he/she can always "create a copy" (ultimately by simply spooling the data from within psql)

Comment: @francs: ya I mean copy command.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name- ya you are right. Is there a way so that I can only make a user view my table that's it with no other access.

Comment: If one is able to view the data in the table he's able to copy it. Of course to copy it somewhere in the DB in question he has to have create privileges on a schema (to create a new table in it), or create privileges on the DB (to create a schema in it, and then table in that schema). You may use that to restrict the "copy" process. But you can't stop him dumping your data and using it elsewhere (different DB, cluster etc.).

Comment: @YogeshMukhi No, because *viewing* a table *requires that you copy the data from the server to the client*, after which it is out of the server's control. You must deal with this at the application level.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL does not directly support what you want - and it's pretty dubious theoretically, too.

Even if you modified PostgreSQL to add a `COPY` permission, the user would just use the [XML table functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-MAPPING), the new [JSON support](http://arstechnica.com/business/2012/01/native-json-features-submitted-for-postgresql-92/), or a plain old `SELECT ... FROM tablename;` to extract the data.

If somebody has `SELECT` rights to a table, they can `COPY ... TO stdout` that table and they can `SELECT ... INTO` another table if they have `CREATE` rights anywhere. This makes sense; after all, they can always `SELECT * FROM tablename;` and process it client-side.

You *can* selectively `GRANT` rights on individual columns, but they can still do a `SELECT allowedcol1, allowedcol2, ... FROM tablename` and therefore a `COPY (SELECT allowedcol1, allowedcol2, ... FROM tablename) TO stdout`.

The only way to (mostly) stop a user from doing a `COPY` or `SELECT INTO` is to force all access through [`SECURITY DEFINER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html) stored procedures that define very limited acess to the table.

A clever user can still write a `COPY (SELECT ...) TO stdout` with a query that uses your stored procedure API to loop over keys and request each one. It'll be slower, but so long as you provide any way to list all the keys in the table it will work.

In the end, if you give them `SELECT` you give them the ability to copy one way or the other.

Comment: Thanks All for making me understand this concept.

Comment: COPY can be used by an attacker / SQL Injection attack to write files to disk. If the DB is running as a privileged user, the attacker could write into /etc/ or .ssh/* and cause damage.

If we can't block access to postgres' COPY command, are OS file access controls the only way to handle this misuse of COPY?

Comment: @rajatbanerjee Don't run your application as the postgres superuser. `GRANT` only the rights you require. `COPY` to/from file is only available to the PostgreSQL superuser. Additionally, you should never run PostgreSQL as root - and it will *refuse* to run as root - so it shouldn't be able to write to `/etc/` anyway.